Azure Data Factory Pipeline Return Value to Parent Pipeline and Switch
I have the following ADF Child Pipeline that is executed from a Parent Pipeline via a Switch Activity.

And in the Set Row Count, I am setting a pipeline return value of:
@activity('Copy Delta to Blob').output.rowsCopied
In my Parent Pipeline, within the Switch, I have:


With the expression being:
@activity('Integration Deltas').output.pipelineReturnValue.RowsCopied
And finally the variables, one being RowsCopied:

Yet I get the following error:
The expression 'activity('Integration Deltas').output.pipelineReturnValue.RowsCopied' cannot be evaluated because property 'RowsCopied' doesn't exist, available properties are ''.
Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

and also, can you show how are you giving the expression in the child pipeline return set variable?

The expression is in the original question @activity('Copy Delta to Blob').output.rowsCopied

if condition false never executes, that is determined by Get Table CT ID i.e. if we have no changed data. I've just realised, it needs a set variable there!!

I have posted an answer about it. Check and let me know if its solved or not.


I have followed same pipeline design as yours and I got same error. The reason for the above error is when the if expression in the child pipeline results False, then the pipeline run won't execute the activities inside the True activities of if activity. That means, there is no Return variable named RowsCopied and that's what the error is saying.
Here, for sample I have given False value to the if activity expression and it raised the above error as there is no activities in the False activities of if.

To resolve this, you need to handle the return variable activity in the case of if activity expression's False.
Create another return variable in this case and pass 0 as there are no rows will be copied.

Now, this will work for both True and False cases of If activity.

